# Swift: NSTableView drag to reorder item how to display cell during dragging

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I am implementing a drag and drop to reorder the cell, everything works but I would like that during dragging the cell view follows the mouse.

I'm using NSTableRowView. I need to make it work with NSTableRowView. If you have an idea how to do ..

The actually result:

[image]

My actually code:

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
        let account = viewModel.formattedServices[row]

        let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
        pasteboardItem.setString(account.id, forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "mymoney.account"))
        return pasteboardItem
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> NSDragOperation {

        if dropOperation == .above {
            return .move
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, row: Int, dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
        guard let item = info.draggingPasteboard.pasteboardItems?.first,
              let theString = item.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "mymoney.account")),
              let account = viewModel.formattedServices.first(where: { $0.id == theString }),
              let originalRow = viewModel.formattedServices.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == account.id })
                else { return false }

        var newRow = row
        // When you drag an item downwards, the "new row" index is actually --1. Remember dragging operation is `.above`.
        if originalRow < newRow {
            newRow = row - 1
        }

        // Animate the rows
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.moveRow(at: originalRow, to: newRow)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        return true
    }
```

I can't find a method to return the cell view during dragging.

For return cell view I'm using `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView?`

And my `NSTableRowView`:

```
class ServicesTableViewCell: NSTableRowView, CustomCelleable {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationCount: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: NSImageView!


    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        isEmphasized = false
    }

    func setup(with item: Celleable) { }
```

Comment: The cell should be displayed automatically. I tried your code and the cell is displayed. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I know what the problem is ... I'm using NSTableRowView. I need to make it work with NSTableRowView. If you have an idea how to do ..

Comment: How do you use `NSTableRowView`?

Comment: Look my edit please

Comment: The cause of the problem is somewhere else. Is it possible to reproduce the problem in a small test project?

Comment: Yes please look at the url: we.tl/t-2v271JH1pQ  . thanks for your help. Let me know

Comment: The cell is not drawn because there is no cell view. Why do you use `NSTableRowView` instead of `NSTableCellView`?

Comment: Because I want to set `isEmphasized = false` it's more beautiful... So there is not solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** `NSTableRowView` can't replace `NSTableCellView`, use `NSTableCellView` for the table cells.

Starting with the test app. In IB, select the column in the table view and add a Text Table Cell View from the library.

[image]

In ViewController.swift replace `tableView(_:rowViewForRow:)` by `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    guard let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
        fatalError()
    }

    cell.textField?.stringValue = array[row].name

    return cell
}
```

In `setTableView()` remove registering the nib.

```
func setTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "mymoney.account")])
}
```

ServicesTableViewCell isn’t used anymore.

**Step 2** Use a subclass of `NSTableRowView` to disable `isEmphasized`:

Add a subclass of `NSTableRowView`, let’s name it `ServicesTableRowView`.

Override `isEmphasized` to make it always `false`.

```
class ServicesTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override var isEmphasized: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
        set {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

}
```

In IB select the table view and add a Custom View from the library. Set the class of the view to `ServicesTableRowView` and the identifier to `NSTableViewRowViewKey`.

[image: Xcode IB]

The modified test project: we.tl/t-yjpZrz6q7g

Comment: Can you upload the code in wetransfer, So I can see the modifications you made, because I did not understand your explanation

Comment: Why must set identifier `NSTableViewRowViewKey` ?

Comment: [NSTableViewRowViewKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewrowviewkey?language=objc) is the default identifier of the row view. If you want to use a different identifier then implement `tableView(_:rowViewForRow:)` and call `tableVIew.makeView(withIdentifier: myCustomRowViewIdentifier, owner: self)`.